# Any tools or frameworks for visualisation of algorithms?

Tags: algorithms

I would like to make animation of algorithms in order for students to see the flow of an algorithm in a visual way.

Like an alternative to https://visualgo.net/en

I want to make custom animations like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a few years ago, there was a large effort to work on algorithm visualization and many tools were developed. [Tom Naps](http://www.uwosh.edu/faculty_staff/naps/) led part of that effort, but I suspect he is now retired.

But a simple google search for "algorithm visualization" will turn up quite a lot of both tools and people.

They aren't hard to build, actually, if you use a language like Java that has a large and sophisticated graphics library.

Comment: Yes Hungarian and flamenco dances on you tube, for search and sort. (also other visualisations on there)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to make animation of algorithms in order for students to
> see the flow of an algorithm in a visual way.

Get the game [Human Resource Machine](https://tomorrowcorporation.com/humanresourcemachine).

Don't believe me then just watch this [video](https://youtu.be/HDrVlvUGfMI?t=217).

What is really nice about this is that if you have a student who is having a problem with a basic concept you can have them play the game and talk about what they are thinking. This often helps in identifying the mental block the student is having and then you can just help them play the game and that should help them learn an analogy that helps them past the mental block.

Comment: We use this game in our core curriculum. It's fantastic!